# VB6 + Crystal report 8.5 not refresh data

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

Hy all,
I am working with VB + Crystal Report 8.5

with the help of a command button I displays the report.

But the problem is the report is not displayed with the new records.

it displays the old records.
for that I am using the RefreshBtn with Crystal Report.
But b’se of that each time I must need to click the RefreshBtn.

Is their any option in crystal report which will refresh data automatically with every print.
Or is their any other option which will displays the latest updated data in report.

Exemple for my Code

```
    **cR1.Connect = ";PWD=myPassword;"
    cR1.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\balance_frs.rpt"
    cR1.DataFiles(0) = App.Path & "\tmp.mdb"
    cR1.ReportTitle = "Balance Client "
    cR1.ReplaceSelectionFormula "{Balance_CL.nom} LIKE '" & Tier.text & "'"        
    cR1.Formulas(0) = "Ste='" & NomSteC & "'"
    cR1.PrintReport**
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Menu File - Report options... - Reporting tab.
Uncheck "Save Data with Report" option.

Comment: Hello.
I have already tried it, but it's the same problem.
as if the CR does not quickly update the data I just added,
I have to take a 5 second break for it to work,
I don't know what the problem is.